# Oracle SQL Merge Query Works in GUI, Fails in PHP Script

Tags: php, oracle

I have an oracle merge query in my application code that just doesn't run.  When I echo out the query and run it in sqldeveloper it runs fine, though.  And oddly enough, I only have this problem with merge queries; with straight insert queries, everything works just fine.

Code Sample:

```
$sql = "merge into table1 c using (select '$value' as value from table1  where ROWNUM=1) cd
    on (c.value = cd.value)
    when matched then
       update set c.col1 = '$col1val', c.col2= '$col2val'
    when not matched then
        insert (c.col2, c.col2, c.col3)
    values ('$col1val', '$col2val', '$col3val')";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 
$result = oci_execute($stid);

//Checking to see if it ran properly
if(!$result)
{
  echo "query failed:  $sql";
}

echo $sql;  //If I copy what gets echoed onto the screen into my db gui and run it, I get '1 row merged' with no warnings or errors
```

In the above code snippet, I always get the "query failed" statement.  Plus, when I check the database I notice that no updates or inserts have been performed.  In contrast, if I were to change the merge query into a straight insert query, such as this:

```
$sql = "insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) 
        values ('$col1val', '$col2val', '$col3val')";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 
$result = oci_execute($stid);

//Checking to see if it ran properly
if(!$result)
{
  echo "query failed:  $sql";
}
```

Then it does not fail at all.  I do not get "query failed" and I see the new rows in the database table.

I am at a loss for why this is happening only for merge queries.  For reference, I am using Oracle 10g and PHP 5.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

************ANSWER FOUND******************

As Roger pointed out, the query needed to be bound.  This is how I resolved the issue:

```
//REMOVE  single quoted variable ('$var') and used binding instead (:val)
$sql = "merge into table1 c using (select :value as value from table1  where ROWNUM=1) cd
    on (c.value = cd.value)
    when matched then
       update set c.col1 = :col1val, c.col2= :col2val
    when not matched then
        insert (c.col2, c.col2, c.col3)
    values (:col1val, :col2val, :col3val)";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 

//BIND VALUES
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col1val", $col1val);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col2val", $col2val);    
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col3val", $col3val);

$result = oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't run, what happens?  Please give us something to go on.  Describe the behaviour, including any outputs such as error messages.

Comment: If you execute the statement "select '$value' as value from dual" from within PHP, what does the VALUE column in the result set have in it?

Comment: @APC:  I update the question to include more details.  I added error checking to see if the query executed.  When it is a merge statement it does not, however when it is an insert statement it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some operating systems  you need to somehow escape special characters like "$" 
another thing to chack is if the os has problems with the sql on multiple lines, som you may need to build up a string with the SQL in it.

Comment: Thanks!  I checked the PHP manual for binding and found examples of oci_bind_by_name.  I used :val instead of '$val' in sql statement and then used oci_bind_by_name() after oci_parse to relace values, and now it works.